# Unable to get SSL working on Tornado

Tags: python, ssl, websocket, tornado

I am trying to implement hiroakis's project (https://github.com/hiroakis/tornado-websocket-example) over SSL.

I made required changes (see below) and also added the Certificate Authority's Public Certificate to Firefox's trusted certificate list. 
When I open `https://localhost:8888`, I get

```
SSLError: [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_BAD_CERTIFICATE] SSLv3 alert bad certificate (_ssl.c:1750)
```

(Entire Traceback):

```
WARNING:tornado.general:error on read
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/iostream.py", line 630, in _handle_read
    pos = self._read_to_buffer_loop()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/iostream.py", line 600, in _read_to_buffer_loop
    if self._read_to_buffer() == 0:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/iostream.py", line 712, in _read_to_buffer
    chunk = self.read_from_fd()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/iostream.py", line 1327, in read_from_fd
    chunk = self.socket.read(self.read_chunk_size)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 603, in read
    v = self._sslobj.read(len or 1024)
SSLError: [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_BAD_CERTIFICATE] sslv3 alert bad certificate (_ssl.c:1750)
ERROR:tornado.general:Uncaught exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/http1connection.py", line 691, in _server_request_loop
    ret = yield conn.read_response(request_delegate)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 807, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/concurrent.py", line 209, in result
    raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 810, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*sys.exc_info())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/http1connection.py", line 166, in _read_message
    quiet_exceptions=iostream.StreamClosedError)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 807, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/concurrent.py", line 209, in result
    raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_exc_info
SSLError: [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_BAD_CERTIFICATE] sslv3 alert bad certificate (_ssl.c:1750)
```

#### Here is the python code:

```
from tornado import websocket, web, ioloop, httpserver
import json

cl = []

class IndexHandler(web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.render("/var/www/html/index.html")

class SocketHandler(websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    def check_origin(self, origin):
        print "Connection Received from ",origin
        return True

    def open(self):
        if self not in cl:
            cl.append(self)

    def on_close(self):
        if self in cl:
            cl.remove(self)

class ApiHandler(web.RequestHandler):

    @web.asynchronous
    def get(self, *args):
        self.finish()
        id = self.get_argument("id")
        value = self.get_argument("value")
        data = {"id": id, "value" : value}
        data = json.dumps(data)
        for c in cl:
            c.write_message(data)

    @web.asynchronous
    def post(self):
        pass

app = web.Application([
    (r'/', IndexHandler),
    (r'/ws', SocketHandler),
    (r'/api', ApiHandler),
    (r'/(favicon.ico)', web.StaticFileHandler, {'path': '../'}),
    (r'/(rest_api_example.png)', web.StaticFileHandler, {'path': './'}),
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    server = httpserver.HTTPServer(app, ssl_options = {
        "certfile": "/local_repo/keys/server.crt",
        "keyfile": "/local_repo/server.key",
    })
    server.listen(8888)                                                                                                                                                                                
    ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Apart from that, I modified `(r'/ws', SocketHandler) to (r'/wss', SocketHandler)`

Similary, the modified index.html (which uses javascript to create socket connection) is:

#### Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>tornado WebSocket example</title>
  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.no-icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>tornado WebSocket example</h1>
    <hr>
      WebSocket status : <span id="message"></span>
    <hr>
    <h3>The following table shows values by using WebSocket</h3>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="span4">
          <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed">
            <tr>
              <th>No.</th><th>id</th><th>value</th>
            </tr>
            <tr id="row1">
              <td> 1 </td><td> id 1 </td><td id="1"> 0 </td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="row2">
              <td> 2 </td><td> id 2 </td><td id="2"> 0 </td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="row3">
              <td> 3 </td><td> id 3 </td><td id="3"> 0 </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div class="span4">
          <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed">
            <tr>
              <th>No.</th><th>id</th><th>value</th>
            </tr>
            <tr id="row4">
              <td> 4 </td><td> id 4 </td><td id="4"> 0 </td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="row5">
              <td> 5 </td><td> id 5 </td><td id="5"> 0 </td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="row6">
              <td> 6 </td><td> id 6 </td><td id="6"> 0 </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div class="span4">
          <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed">
            <tr>
              <th>No.</th><th>id</th><th>value</th>
            </tr>
            <tr id="row7">
              <td> 7 </td><td> id 7 </td><td id="7"> 0 </td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="row8">
              <td> 8 </td><td> id 8 </td><td id="8"> 0 </td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="row9">
              <td> 9 </td><td> id 9 </td><td id="9"> 0 </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>

    <hr>
    <h3>REST API examples (use appropriate certificates with curl)</h3>
    <ol>
      <li>Set the "id 1" value to 100
        <ul><li>curl "https://localhost:8888/api?id=1&amp;value=100"</li></ul>
      </li>
      <li>Set the "id 1" value to 300 ( The row No 1 will change to yellow )
        <ul><li>curl "https://localhost:8888/api?id=1&amp;value=300"</li></ul>
      </li>
      <li>Set The "id 1" value to 600 ( The row No 1 will change to red )
        <ul><li>curl "https://hiroakis.com:8888/api?id=1&amp;value=600"</li></ul>
      </li>
    </ol>
    <ul>
      <li>value 201 - 500 : change to yellow</li>
      <li>value 501 - : change to red</li>
    </ul>
    <img src="./rest_api_example.png"/>
  </div>
  <script>
    var ws = new WebSocket('wss://localhost:8888/ws');
    var $message = $('#message');

    ws.onopen = function(){
      $message.attr("class", 'label label-success');
      $message.text('open');
    };
    ws.onmessage = function(ev){
      $message.attr("class", 'label label-info');
      $message.hide();
      $message.fadeIn("slow");
      $message.text('recieved message');

      var json = JSON.parse(ev.data);
      $('#' + json.id).hide();
      $('#' + json.id).fadeIn("slow");
      $('#' + json.id).text(json.value);

      var $rowid = $('#row' + json.id);
      if(json.value > 500){
        $rowid.attr("class", "error");
      }
      else if(json.value > 200){
        $rowid.attr("class", "warning");
      }
      else{
        $rowid.attr("class", "");
      }
    };
    ws.onclose = function(ev){
      $message.attr("class", 'label label-important');
      $message.text('closed');
    };
    ws.onerror = function(ev){
      $message.attr("class", 'label label-warning');
      $message.text('error occurred');
    };

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I created SSL certificates using these steps:

**Create the CA private key:**

```
openssl genrsa -des3 -out servercakey.pem
```

**Create the CA public certificate** *(When you create a certificate, there must be one unique name (a Distinguished Name (DN)), which is different for each certificate that you create):*

```
openssl req -new -x509 -key servercakey.pem -out root.crt
```

**Create the server's private key file:**

```
openssl genrsa -out server.key
```

**Create the server certificate request:**

```
openssl req -new -out reqout.txt -key server.key
```

**Use the CA private key file to sign the server's certificate:**

```
openssl x509 -req -in reqout.txt -days 3650 -sha1 -CAcreateserial -CA root.crt -CAkey servercakey.pem -out server.crt
```

**Create the client's private key file:**

```
openssl genrsa -out client.key
```

**Create the client certificate request:**

```
openssl req -new -out reqout.txt -key client.key
```

**Use the CA private key file to sign the client's certificate:**

```
openssl x509 -req -in reqout.txt -days 3650 -sha1 -CAcreateserial -CA root.crt -CAkey servercakey.pem -out client.crt
```

**Creating pem file for Server:**

```
cat server.crt root.crt > server.pem
```

Comment: what version of python are you using

Comment: I am using python 2.7.8

Comment: Now I am getting another error:
`SSLError: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_UNKNOWN_CA] tlsv1 alert unknown ca (_ssl.c:1750)
`

Comment: Are you really having the cert in the /keys/ folder and the key outside this folder? This is unusual.

Comment: `tlsv1 alert unknown CA` is send back by the client because it does not know and trust the CA which signed the certificate . The CA needs to be added to the trust store of the client. How this is done depends on the client.

Comment: Yes, I have the keys in the folder and I'm using firefox or chrome browser to just access https://localhost:8888. I have added the root.crt (which is my CAs public certificate).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finally today I was able to find the source of problem.

When I was creating the certificates, in the FQDN (fully qualified domain name) part of creating certificate, I had entered 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost)

Whats surprising is that neither chrome nor firefox alerted me that I was accessing a website with the CA whose **subject name** did not match the target's **host name**.

It was only when I tried with **curl**, `curl https://localhost:8888/` that it alerted me.

I think browsers are supposed to do that, don't they?

I also noted that my `/etc/hosts` file has `127.0.0.1` mapped to `localhost`. Then why is it that transferring data using curl to localhost fails but to 127.0.0.1 succeeds?